# Password Case Sensitivity using BINARY from MYSQL to SQLSRV

Tags: php, mysql, case-sensitive, sqlsrv

I wonder if someone can help me here.

Basically, I'm trying to make my login script case-sensitive especially when inputting a password.

I successfully made it work perfectly in PHP MYSQL using the below code, using a BINARY:

```
$qry="SELECT * FROM studentrecords WHERE username='$login' AND password=**BINARY**'".($_POST['password'])."'";
```

I've tried using it in PHP SQLSRV, but it is not working.

Anyone can tell me an alternative way or how to make it work in PHP SQLSRV?

Thanks in advance, I'll appreciate it alot.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL Server database's default search option is probably case insensitive. You can easily change this setting for your query like below by using `COLLATE`:

```
$qry="SELECT * FROM studentrecords WHERE username='$login' AND password COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS ='".($_POST['password'])."'";
```

You should look at the usage of parameterized queries for avoiding SQL injections. Microsoft's official  [SQLSRV Driver API Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/cc296162(v=sql.105).aspx) has very good examples.

[Much more information about `COLLATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx)